# calculate and set the height for some div (initial settings). When the height of the browser window is changed --> change the height for div

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize

I need calculate and set the height for some div (initial settings). When the height of the browser window is changed --> change the height for div.

How will be better to rewrite this code (I want do initial settings once and change it when window resize):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var height = document.documentElement.clientHeight - 500;
    if (height < 135) {
        height = 135;
    }
    document.getElementById('left_space').style.height = height + 'px';

    $(window).resize(function () {
        var height = document.documentElement.clientHeight - 500;
        if (height < 135)
        {
            height = 135;
        }
        document.getElementById('left_space').style.height = height + 'px';
    });
});
```

Comment: your question is not clear, resize it to what ? if to what you are doing , it should be working fine !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are purely looking to tidy up the code, it could look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var resizeIt = function() {
      var height = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight - 500, 135);
      $('#left_space').css('height', height + 'px');
    };

    resizeIt();

    $(window).resize(function () {
        resizeIt();
    });
});
```

Here I have pulled out the lines of code that set the height into their own function, so the code is not duplicated. Then I took advantage of some of the shorter syntax you can use in jQuery for finding and changing styles of elements.

Answer (score 1):

is that what you are looking for?

[api.jquery.com](http://api.jquery.com/resize/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

$(window).resize(function() {
   var height = document.documentElement.clientHeight - 500;
    if (height < 135) {
        height = 135;
    }
    document.getElementById('left_space').style.height = height + 'px';

    jQuery(window).resize(function () {
        var height = document.documentElement.clientHeight - 500;
        if (height < 135)
        {
            height = 135;
        }
        document.getElementById('left_space').style.height = height + 'px';
    });

});


});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think jQuery(window).resize one would be good